# Fire event on Bootstrap carousel slide issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, slide

I try to use this code to fire on an event upon carousel slide, but it fails to work for some reason. Any suggestions?

```
var $carousel = $('#carousel-showcase');
$carousel.carousel();

$carousel.bind('slide', function(e) {

  setTimeout( function(){
    var left = $carousel.find('.item.active.left');
    var right = $carousel.find('.item.active.right');
    if(left.length > 0) {
    $("#wrap").animate({
        backgroundPositionX: '+=50%'
    },0);
    }
    else if(right.length > 0) {
    $("#wrap").animate({
        backgroundPositionX: '-=50%'
    },0);
    }
  }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 changed the 'slide' event to 'slide.bs.carousel'.  Change to this and it should work (assuming that is your only issue):

```
$carousel.bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    console.log('slide event!');
});
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131280/fire-event-on-carousel-slide-not-slid-event-bootstrap-3?noredirect=1#comment30002064_20131280).

Comment: it works in Chrome, but fails to work in Mozilla. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, it turned out that Mozilla has problems with animate(backgroundPositionX). I managed to fix it with a plugin. Now it works fine.

Comment: I have searched everywhere for this question and finally got this answer. Thanks.