# Fire event on carousel slide (not slid) event, Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap 2 seems to work fine handling the slide event (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651466/how-to-attach-slide-slid-events-to-the-bootstrap-toolkits-carousel)) with the following code:

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slide', function (e) {
    console.log('slide event!');
});
```

I cannot, however, get the same things to work in Bootstrap 3 (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/yYk9R/32/)). Anyone know why?

Comment: how about using `.on()` instead of `.bind()`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Actual event namespace for `slide` according to bootstrap3 implementation is [slide.bs.carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) as opposed to `slide` which was the one acc: to BS2, also use `slid.bs.carousel` to track completion of slide (though `slid` seems to work.)

So try:

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    console.log('slide event!');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9fwuq/)**

Comment: is there an event for carousel init or start?

Answer (score 9):

**On Slide before**

```
h('#HomeSlider').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
   alert(h('#HomeSlider .item.active').html());
});
```

**On Slide After**

```
h('#HomeSlider').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
   alert(h('#HomeSlider .item.active').html());
});
```