# bootstrap carousel slide event not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add slide event to carousel but its not firing up

```
<div id="background-carousel">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active" style="background-image:url('images/Home BG 1.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="item" style="background-image:url('images/Home BG 3.jpg')"></div>
        <div class="item" style="background-image:url('images/home_bg2.jpg')"></div>  
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my javascript but its not working and not showing any alert on image slide

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {


     $('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 4000
 });

 $('#myCarousel').on('slide', function () {
  alert("Slide Event");
 // console.log('slid event');
  });

  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fire event on Bootstrap carousel slide issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129290/fire-event-on-bootstrap-carousel-slide-issue)

Answer (score 6):

Try This

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    alert("Slide Event");
    //console.log('slid event');
});
```

There are two supported methods

**slide.bs.carousel**
This event fires immediately when the slide instance method is called.

**slid.bs.carousel**
This event is fired when the carousel has completed its slide transition.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap carousel provide events while slide are:-

1. `slid.bs.carousel`
2. `slide.bs.carousel`

Check below:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myCarousel").on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
     alert('Finished sliding');
   });
});
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myCarousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
     alert('Finished sliding');
  });
});
```

Comment: @AlivetoDie do i need to delete it

Comment: pls check https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp

event : slid.bs.carousel will be triggered after the carousel sliding is completed.

event : slide.bs.carousel will be triggered before the carousel sliding is about to start.

Comment: still not working for me, don't understand why!! I'm using the same code